# Error getting likeCount to save

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, counter

I'm trying to update an object in ios with a likeCount.  Below is my current code and errors

```
NSNumber *likeCount = [self.currentItem.pfObj valueForKey:@"likeCount"];
  NSLog(@"Initial number of likes --->  %@", likeCount);
  likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] + 1];
  NSLog(@"New number of likes --->  %@", likeCount);

  PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MainItem"];
  [query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.currentItem.likeCount
                block:^(PFObject *upLikeCount, NSError *error) {
  NSLog(@"Post query number of likes --->  %@", likeCount);
  upLikeCount = likeCount;
  NSLog(@"New count of likes --->  %@", upLikeCount);
  [upLikeCount saveInBackground];
       }];
```

The like count is increasing as expected in the log, but I can't get it to save to the object.  I was initially creating a new object with the count.  Now (code above I'm querying for item but getting error "Incompatible pointer types assigning PFObject from NSNumber" in xCode and

in logs:

```
Initial number of likes --->  1
New number of likes --->  2
-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d12345
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17d12345'
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the value to the field within your object, not the object itself.

Also, since you already have the object there is no need to fetch it first - you can just save it -

```
NSNumber *likeCount = [self.currentItem.pfObj valueForKey:@"likeCount"];
NSLog(@"Initial number of likes --->  %@", likeCount);
likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] + 1];
NSLog(@"New number of likes --->  %@", likeCount);

self.currentItem.pfObj[@"likeCount"]=likeCount;

[self.currentItem.pfObj saveInBackground];
```

You can use the `PFObject` method `incrementKey` to even further simplify your code

```
[self.currentItem.pfObj incrementKey:@"likeCount"];
[self.currentItem.pfObj saveInBackground];
```

Comment: Thanks Paul!  Exactly what I need. I had gotten thrown off by https://www.parse.com/questions/update-objects-in-class-in-ios